# CSS projection mapping / quad warping / corner pin

Tags: css

I want to map a rectangular texture to a quad with corners in arbitrary positions corresponding to screen pixels. Something like `drawQuad( x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4 )`. Are there any demos of doing this with WebGL?

Everything that I have done with WebGL has been with Three.js, which makes geometry projection, lighting, and camera easy. But this is simpler: no need for lighting or camera angles, just inputting the absolute position of the four corners. I'm not opposed to using Three.js if I can get on this lower level.

I found [an explanation with a GLSL vertex shader](http://www.memo.tv/archive/projection_mapping_quad_warping_with_quartz_composer_vdmx) in Quartz Composer.

---

Update

In my project I ended up going with CSS for now, because I can stretch any element (canvas, img, div, video), and don't get the tearing with non-planar shapes... Eventually I might revisit the WebGL option. If anybody has an example dragging four corners to arbitrary positions, I'll add it here.

[image: meemoo mapper]

Comment: Found a demo using CSS3D: http://www.is-real.net/experiments/css3/wonder-webkit/

Comment: Here's comprehensive explanation and demo of the matrix math required to do this in CSS: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/78081

Comment: you need css3 or webgl code?

Comment: Exploring the options, but this question is about WebGL.

Comment: I've modified the answer. Check for the live example.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest reading tutorials from "Learning webGL".

For every vertex of quad you send its "UV coordinates". UV coordinates are vec2 data that tell which part of the texture is bound with vertex.

So for example, (0,0) uv represents upper left corner of the texture, while (0.3, 0.4) represents position on the texture that corresponds to 30% width of the texture and 40% heights.

In GLSL shader, there is a special function - texture2D, and here's the usage:

```
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
varying vec2 vUV;
void main()
    vec4 color_from_texture = texture2D ( uTexture, vUV );
    gl_FragColor = color_from_texture;
}
```

This is called sampling texture, and you read data from texture at some position by calling texture2D function.

So for quad, vertices would have positions (x1, y1), (x2, y1), (x1, y2), (x2, y2) and their corresponding UV coordinates would be (0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0,0), (0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0).
Note how we streched texture by defining UV coordinates fully from one point to another.

Vertex shader would look something like this:

```
attribute vec2 aUV;
attribute vec2 aVertexPos;
varying vec2 vUV;
void main() {
    vUV = aUv;
    gl_Position = vec4( aVertexPos, 1.0); // maybe modelViewMatrix * projMatrix * vec4(aVertexPos, 1.0)
}
```

Shader will interpolate UV coordinates between vertices that combine one triangle so each fragment will get its own, interpolated value fro UV and thus will sample different texture data.

Read carefully this, and after that, creating quad should be easy:
http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=507

Hope this helps.

- - - 

Live example: http://abstract-algorithm.com/quad.html

Comment: I can definitely learn from the example, but the animation is changing x, y, z rotation. How hard would it be to directly define the four corners of the quad? Like `drawScene(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4)`

Comment: you can find in the source code of the live example 'vertices' array. By changing values in it you can directly change position of corners.
You could write function draw_quad(xy1, xy2, xy3, xy4) that would do what you want. You could also use THREE.js or some other engine, but I don't know how well would that suit your needs.

Comment: I'll also need more vertices, and a vertex shader to interpolate the corners, since this kind of warp makes the triangles obvious: http://i.imgur.com/FvYeVzh.png

Comment: images should be nice looking if all vertices are planar. if they're not then warping becomes too obvious, as expected. from the link and videos that you gave, you can see that quad is always planar, but that's up to calculation of the position of the 4th vertex, depending on the positions of the first three vertices.

Comment: do you need something more? tell me if you even more help. :)

Comment: In my project I ended up going with CSS for now, because I can stretch any element (canvas, img, div, video), and don't get the tearing with non-planar shapes. http://www.flickr.com/photos/forresto/8759741112/ ... Eventually I might revisit the WebGL option.

Comment: okay. it really isn't that hard. you could also use three.js's support of quads and that could save you some trouble.